# set toc via TemplateProcessor using phpword

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword, tableofcontents

Template.docx has predefined topic(heading1). I load Template.docx in templateprocessor to create table of content based on predefined heading.

Template.docx layout

```
${TOC}
pagebreak
Topic1
```

createToc.php

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('template.docx');

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$fontStyle = ['spaceAfter' => 60, 'size' => 12];

$phpWord->addTitleStyle(1, ['size' => 14, 'color' => '000000', 'bold' => true]);

$toc = $section->addTOC($fontStyle);
$toc->setMinDepth(1);
$toc->setMaxDepth(1);

$xmlWriter      = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\XMLWriter(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\XMLWriter::STORAGE_MEMORY, './', \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::hasCompatibility());
$containerWriter= new PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\Container($xmlWriter, $section);
$containerWriter->write();
$elXml          = $xmlWriter->getData();
 \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(false);
 $templateProcessor->setValue('TOC',$elXml);
 \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);
$templateProcessor->saveAs('toc_output.docx');
```

toc_output.docx

```
pagebreak
Topic1
```

There is no table of content in output file.